# Conversion of UTF String to InputStream

Tags: java, xml, java-me, utf-8, xml-parsing

I am trying to get XML data from a MIDP device to a Servlet. Servlet is obtaining the Data as follows -

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream((InputStream) request.getInputStream());
        String readUTF = dis.readUTF();
```

After getting this done from MIDP I thought it was over. But now I am having trouble converting the readUTF to a InputStream. I want to parse the xml string. I used kXML 2.3.0 and here is the code -

```
XmlPullParser xpp = new KXmlParser();
                try {
                    xpp.setInput(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(readUTF.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
                    int event = xpp.getEventType();
                    if (event != xpp.END_DOCUMENT) {
                        System.out.println("Inside Document");
                        if (xpp.getName() != null) {
                            System.out.println("The tag is not null");
                            if (xpp.getName().equals("title")) {
                                System.out.println("Title =" + xpp.getText());
                            } else if (xpp.getName().equals("note")) {
                                System.out.println("Note =" + xpp.getText());
                            } else if (xpp.getName().equals("priority")) {
                                System.out.println("Priority =" + xpp.getText());
                            }
                        }
                        event = xpp.next();
                    }
                }
```

The problem I am having is that only Inside Document is ever printed. That means that the second print statement doesn't get a chance to execute. I used Dom4j for the same thing.

```
SAXReader sr = new SAXReader();
sr.read(stringReader);
System.out.println(sr.getDocumentFactory().createDocument().asXML());
```

The result is something is this just this -

```
INFO: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Original string is - `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> <data> <task><title>dsfsdfds</title><note>null</note><priority>High</priority></task><task><title>sdfsdfdsf</title><note>null</note><priority>High</priority></task> </data>`

I validated XML for it and it works perfectly. Is there a problem for converting UTF-8 to InputStreams? And is there another way to parse my XML String to data.

Comment: You say that "the second print statement doesn't get a chance to execute" - why don't you add an `else` clause to show if `xpp.getName()` *is* null?

Comment: But then it means that there is no node there right since null is returning?

Comment: Well, it means it's not a start/end element node, or an entity reference. It could be TEXT, or START_DOCUMENT etc.

Comment: Oh...Then how can I shift the code to make it work?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but you should probably be looping around until `event` is `xpp.END_DOCUMENT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about your `XmlPullParser` code, but your dom4j code is broken. You've asked the SAXReader to give you its document *factory*, which you're then asking for a *new document*, and then you're printing it. In other words, that has nothing to do with the data that's been read from `stringReader`. You're *ignoring* the result of the `read` call. Try this instead:

```
SAXReader sr = new SAXReader();
Document doc = sr.read(stringReader);
System.out.println(doc.asXML());
```

See whether that shows the complete XML.

I note that in the `XmlPullParser` code you're not looping round as you normally would - you're only reading the first node, examining it, then reassigning the value of `event` - and then not doing anything else.